Reducible and indecomposable modules/representations
This is perhaps a soft question regarding terminology but I am somewhat confused by the similar posts I've seen. Note: I am not necessarily considering representaitons of finite groups (i.e. indecomposability is not equivalent to simplicity).
Question: If a module $M$ is not irreducible (hence reducible?), is it then necessarily a direct sum of indecomposable modules? Reducibility implies that there exists a nontrivial proper submodule $N$ of $M$, but of course $M$ may itself be indecomposable, whereas the second stackexchange source claims that we have $M=N\oplus N^\prime$ for some other proper submodule $N^\prime$ (where there is no mention of finite-dimensionality).
Thanks in advance for any indication on this,
M

Semisimple implies complete reducibility
Reducible modules and representations
Irreducible vs. indecomposable representation

A module $M$ is reducible if there is a nontrivial submodule $N$, i.e., $0 \subset N \subset M$, where the inclusions are proper. But there are lots of examples of such submodules that do not have a complement $P$ such that $M \cong N \oplus P$. For example, in abelian groups ($\mathbb{Z}$-modules), $0 \subset 2\mathbb{Z}_4 \subset \mathbb{Z}_4$ is an irreducible submodule with without a complement. In fact, it turns out that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is indecomposable, and more generally, $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}, \; r \geq 1$ is indecomposable.
In general, we have
$$
M \text{ decomposable} \implies M \text{ reducible}
$$
and the contrapositive
$$
M \text{ irreducible} \implies M \text{ indecomposable}.
$$
But the converses are not true in general.
However, there are certain categories of modules where the converses are true, and that's notable. In the representation of finite groups over a field of characteristic that doesn't divide the order of the group, Maschke's theorem is an important such result.
Your confusion in the second link you provide is related to another such category: finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{k}$. We can always extend a basis of a vector subspace to a basis of the entire vector space, so as vector spaces every subspace splits. In fact, every finite dimensional vector space is completely reducible (semisimple), where the irreducible components are the $1$-dimensional spans of each basis vector: if $V = \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{k}}\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$, then $V = \mathbb{k}v_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{k}v_n$.

None of this is special to modules over a group ring, so let's just assume we have some ring $A$ and a left module $M$.
$M$ is called simple or irreducible if there are exactly two submodules (which are then necessarily $M \neq 0$ and $0$).
$M$ is indecomposable if $M \neq 0$ and $M=M_1\oplus M_2$ for submodule $M_1,M_2\leq M$ implies $M_1=0$ or $M_2=0$.
$M$ is called semisimple (also known as completley reducible) if the following equivalent conditions are satisfied:

$M$ is a sum of simple submodules.
$M$ is a direct sum of simple submodules.
If $N \leq M$ is a submodule, then there exists a complement, i.e. a submodule $K \leq M$ such that $M=N\oplus K$.

Here are the relations between these notions and examples from representation theory:
If $M$ is simple, then $M$ is indecomposable and semisimple. Conversely if $M$ is indecomposable and semisimple, $M$ is simple.
$M$ can be semisimple without being simple: just take a direct product of your two favourite irreducible representations. Maschke's theorem says that if $G$ is a finite group and $K$ is a field of characteristic coprime to $|G|$, then every $K[G]$-module is semisimple.
$M$ can be indecomposable without being simple: let $k$ be a field and let $G$ be the additive group of $k$. $G$ acts on $k^2$ via transvections $g(a,b)=(a+gb,b)$. I claim that this $k[G]$ module has exactly three submodules: $0$ $k \times \{0\}$ and $k^2$. Indeed, let $V \subset k^2$ be any nonzero submodule. Then $V$ contains some nonzero vector $(a,b) \in k^2$. If $b \neq 0$, then if $g=1 \in G$ (this not the neutral element! we are in an additive group.), we get $g(a,b)=(a+b,b)$. Now the set $\{(a,b),(a+b,b)\}$ is linearly independent, hence $V=k^2$. This leaves exactly the possibilites I mentioned. From this list of submodules, it's not hard to figure out that this module is indecomposable, but not simple.
I would try to avoid the terminology of reducible, because that could mean not irreducible or completely reducible, depending on the author.
It's worth mentioning that in a lot of situations relevant in representation theory, modules happen to be a direct sum of indecomposable submodules (though this is not always true in full algebraic generality): if $A$ is an algebra over a field $k$, then every module $M$ that is finite-dimensional over $k$ is a direct sum of indecomposable submodules. More generally, this holds if $M$ is of finite length. (See the Krull-Remark-Schmidt theorem for more info on such decompositions.)
I hope this clarifies things.
